# Loading data from datasteam to BigQuery using Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm using API calls to retrieve data from a service.
The data is Nested Json with arrays that might also contain Json objects.

Example:
[image]

Basically I want to upload it to tables within BigQuery.
I created a table per array. Jason objects unpacked in the same table.
For example:

```
Orders: All customer fields, all ShippingAdress, orderDateUtc etc..
Orders_items:  orderid, discountEach, giftTo etc..
Order_items_historicalCategories: ....
```

I'm not sure about the best way to do that.
I can create CSV files from the API call (data steam) and then use COPY per CSV to upload them but it seems excessive. I'm looking for a way to skip the CSV creation.

Is there an operator or package that can handle this data and directly upload it to the tables? I assume that what I need to do has already been done by many other organizations yet I didn't see any "build-in" method to do that in the docs
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have to follow documentation on how to [load json data using python](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_json_data_into_a_new_table), using [nested and repeated fields](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#specifying_nested_and_repeated_fields). For instance, using the schema from the latter link, you can load nested and repeated JSON data in the following manner (you can test with the sample data found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_nested_and_repeated_json_data)):

```
import sys

def load_nested_json():
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    client = bigquery.Client()

    dataset_id, table_id, uri = sys.argv[1:]
    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField('id', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('first_name', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('last_name', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('dob', 'DATE', mode='NULLABLE'),
        bigquery.SchemaField('addresses', 'RECORD', mode='REPEATED', fields=[
            bigquery.SchemaField('status', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('address', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('city', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('state', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('zip', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
            bigquery.SchemaField('numberOfYears', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
        ]),
    ]
    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
    # Uncomment following lines to also create the destination table
    # table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, job_config.schema)
    # table = client.create_table(table)

    # print('Created table {}'.format(table.full_table_id))

    job_config.source_format = "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"

    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri,
        table_ref,
        job_config=job_config)  # API request

    assert load_job.job_type == 'load'

    load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.

    assert load_job.state == 'DONE'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_nested_json()
```

Comment: Thx. Why create_table call? Shouldn't the table be pre-created? Also, must I hard codded the field names? Say I have 16 different API calls can't it get the column names for the Json file?

Comment: You don't **have** to create the table. I changed my answer to reflect that. The python client library does not support loading the schema from a JSON file (check [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3419#issuecomment-356619931)) but that's a feature already requested, currently in the ["To Do" list](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/projects/5).

Comment: OK... but the problem with this method is that I must list all the columns in the code.. That is not very generic and I have like 150 columns from just 1 API call. (I have 6 more API calls). Is this the only way?

Comment: Well you could write a method to parse a json file with the table's schema and pass the output to `LoadJobConfig().schema`. I think that's the best you can get with python, unless you see something I'm missing in the [docs](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html). You can also use the `bq` cli which supports passing the schema as a json file (look up `bq load`).